# Does store.find() method use different inflection rules from ember-inflector?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building a simple Ember application using Ember v1.0.0 and Ember-Data v1.0.0-beta.3. I have a model called 'Categoria'

categoria.coffee:

```
App.Categoria = DS.Model.extend
  nombre: DS.attr 'string'
  simplified: DS.attr 'boolean'
  candidatos: DS.hasMany 'candidato'
```

When I try to find a 'Categoria' by it's id, I always get error message:
**Assertion failed: No model was found for 'categorium'**

categoria_route.coffee:

```
App.CategoriaRoute = Em.Route.extend(
  model: (params)->
    @store.find('categoria', params.categoria_id)
)

App.CategoriaIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    categoria = @modelFor('categoria')
    categoria.reload() if categoria.get('simplified') 
    categoria
)
```

I've specified the inflections rules, due the spanish-named model.

store.coffee:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('categoria', 'categorias')
Ember.Inflector.inflector.rules.irregularInverse['categorias'] = 'categoria'
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter()
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend()
```

I'm wondering if the **find method of the Store uses a different set of inflections rules?** or is there any other place where I should declare the inflection rules for this model?

It worths to mention that requests to the server for this model are made correctly (to the right URL) and they're responded well formed.

I've tried to use different syntax for the `store.find` method as mentioned in the [Ember Guides#Method Find](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find) (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find) but the error is the same.

Comment: That's kind of funny, it uses the ember inflector rules. let me see if we can track it down for you.

Comment: @kingpin2k: Thanks! I lost a day with the problem, I never thought about "Ember.Inflector.inflector.singular" but it worked nice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is when it tries to singularize the json response, it attempts to singularize `categoria` and it returns `categorium`, your pluralization was working fine.

```
var iff = Ember.Inflector.inflector;

iff.irregular('categoria', 'categorias');
// this adds a test for when it finds categoria and you are trying to singularize, return categoria
iff.singular(/categoria/, 'categoria');
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ICeGuzuX/3/edit